# Why am I not getting the expected result with this AJAX & PHP validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to integrate AJAX into my form submissions. I have a pretty well established method for submitting the forms currently but would like to move away from the whole submit, reload page thing.

I'm completely new to AJAX and JQUERY so am on a steep learning curve. I'm trying to get to a point where my existing PHP can be integrated into the AJAX form submit. What I'm stuck on is the ability to send the validation result to the script.

I currently have this on my form processing php

UPDATED WITH NEW CODE FROM FEEDBACK RECEIVED

```
$return = array();
if($validation->passed()) {
  try {
    $getPassageId = Input::get('passageId'); //Get the passage plan id passed via the form
    $latitude = convertDMSToDecimal(Input::get('lat'));
    $longitude = convertDMSToDecimal(Input::get('long'));
    $insertIntoWaypoints = DB::getInstance()->insert('ym_waypoints', array(
      'vessel_id' => $vid,
      'user_id' => $uid,
      'waypoint_num' => Input::get('waypoint'),
      'waypoint_name' => Input::get('waypointName'),
      'latitude' => $latitude,
      'longitude' => $longitude,
      'cts' => Input::get('courseToSteer'),
      'dtw' => Input::get('DistanceToWaypoint'),
      'hw_time' => Input::get('HWTime'),
      'hw_height' => Input::get('HWHeight'),
      'lw_time' => Input::get('LWTime'),
      'lw_height' => Input::get('LWHeight'),
      'chart_num' => Input::get('chartNumbers'),
      'almanac' => Input::get('almanacPages'),
      'radio_signals' => Input::get('radioPages'),
      'por' => Input::get('por'),
      'por_almanac' => Input::get('porAlmanac'),
      'por_vhf' => Input::get('porVHF'),
      'vhf' => Input::get('vhf'),
      'passage_note' => Input::get('notes')
    ));
    $recordID = $insertIntoWaypoints;
    $insertInto = DB::getInstance()->insert('ym_passageplan_route', array(
      'passageplan_id' => $getPassageId,
      'waypoint_id' => $recordID
    ));
    $return['success'] = True;
    $return['message'] = 'successful!';
    print json_encode($return);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    $return['success'] = False;
    $return['message'] = 'fail';
    print json_encode($return);
  }
} else {
  foreach (array_combine($validation->errors(), $validation->fields()) as $error => $field) {
    // Append an array of the error data to $return.
    $return['success'] = False;
    $return['message'] .= $error;
  }
  print json_encode($return);
}
```

And this is the script I'm using to send the data

```
      $(routePlan_form).submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/pages/voyages/passageplans/createroute.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $("#routePlan_form").serialize(),
    'success': function(data) {
      if(data['success']) {
        //refresh the table
        $("#table").load(location.href + " #table");
        //reset the form
        $('#routePlan_form').trigger("reset");
        //scroll to the top
        window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
        //send the user a success message
        resetToastPosition();
        $.toast({
          heading: 'Success',
          text: 'Waypoint added successfully',
          textColor: 'white',
          showHideTransition: 'slide',
          hideAfter : 7000,
          icon: 'success',
          loaderBg: '#f96868',
          position: 'top-center'
        })
      } else {
        // var i;
        // for (i = 0; i < data['message'].length; i++) {
        // this.error(this.xhr, data['message']);
        // }
        this.error(this.xhr, data['message']);
      }
    },
    'error': function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus);
    }
  })
})  
});
```

When intentionally submitting the form I am leaving out the required fields which should send the validation errors back. After the fantastic help below i'm now getting the expected errors in the console. However they are listed as "Waypoint number is required.Waypoint name is required.Latitude is required.Longitude is required."

What I need to be able to do is split this list into individual messages....

I'm assuming I need some sort of foreach or $.each statement but new to JQuery that I'm unsure how to progress...

As a stretch goal I'd also like a way of adding the following into the whole thing so I can alert the user to the incorrect fields

```
          $("#<?php echo $field ?>").addClass("form-control-danger");
      $('<label id="<?php echo $field ?>-error" class="badge badge-danger" for="<?php echo $field ?>"><?php echo $error ?></label>').insertAfter("#<?php echo $field ?>");
```

Any pointers would be fantastic!

Regards

Matt

A quick update---

I'm getting closer! I now have the following code in the processing php file

```
foreach (array_combine($validation->errors(), $validation->fields()) as $error => $field) {
    // Append an array of the error data to $return.
    $return['success'] = False;
    $return['message'] .= [$error];
  }
  print json_encode($return);
```

And the following to loop through the messages

```
else {
         var i;
         for (i = 0; i < data['message'].length; i++) {
         this.error(this.xhr, data['message']);
         }
        //this.error(this.xhr, data['message']);
      }
    },
    'error': function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      //send the user a success message
      resetToastPosition();
      $.toast({
        heading: 'Error',
        text: '' + textStatus,
        textColor: 'white',
        showHideTransition: 'slide',
        hideAfter : 10000,
        icon: 'error',
        bgColor: '#f96868',
        position: 'top-center',
        loaderBg: '#405189'
      })
    }
```

This gives me 5 pop-up error messages, however the text states ArrayArrayArrayArray so I know it's getting the 4 errors as I expected. I think what is happening is that I am adding the error into the $return['message'] array so we are being output a, b, c, d etc. I think I need to add an array into the 'message' array?? Any pointers where to / how to get the error message or where I'm going wrong?

Getting closer!!!

Thinking about the logic behind what is going on I'm now closer again I think. I now get just four messages (as I'd expect with this form) but all the messages are grouped together in each message box, so I added the variable 'i' as a reference to the 'messages' part in it now displays the messages as I'd expect!! Woop woop!

Just need to work out how to add some classes to the fields and we are all good!

parts I'm editing in the Processing page

```
$return = array();
$messages = array();
$return['success'] = False;
foreach (array_combine($validation->errors(), $validation->fields()) as $error => $field) {
    // Append an array of the error data to $return.
    array_push($messages, $error);
    //$return['message'] = array($error);
  }
  $return['message'] = $messages;
  echo json_encode($return);
```

and the ajax call on the form page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(routePlan_form).submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/pages/voyages/passageplans/createroute.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $("#routePlan_form").serialize(),
    'success': function(data) {
      if(data['success']) {
        //refresh the table
        $("#table").load(location.href + " #table");
        //reset the form
        $('#routePlan_form').trigger("reset");
        //scroll to the top
        window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
        //send the user a success message
        resetToastPosition();
        $.toast({
          heading: 'Success',
          text: 'Waypoint added successfully',
          textColor: 'white',
          showHideTransition: 'slide',
          hideAfter : 7000,
          icon: 'success',
          loaderBg: '#f96868',
          position: 'top-center'
        })
      } else {
         var i;
         for (i = 0; i < data['message'].length; i++) {
         this.error(this.xhr, data['message'][i]);
         }
      }
    },
    'error': function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      //send the user a success message
      resetToastPosition();
      $.toast({
        heading: 'Error',
        text: '' + textStatus,
        textColor: 'white',
        showHideTransition: 'slide',
        hideAfter : 10000,
        icon: 'error',
        bgColor: '#f96868',
        position: 'top-center',
        loaderBg: '#405189'
      })
    }
  })
})
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

I had to move the logic around in the processing php

```
$return = array();
$messages = array();
$fields = array();
$return['success'] = False;
if($validation->passed()) {
  try {
    $getPassageId = Input::get('passageId'); //Get the passage plan id passed via the form
    $latitude = convertDMSToDecimal(Input::get('lat'));
    $longitude = convertDMSToDecimal(Input::get('long'));
    $insertIntoWaypoints = DB::getInstance()->insert('ym_waypoints', array(
      'vessel_id' => $vid,
      'user_id' => $uid,
      'waypoint_num' => Input::get('waypoint'),
      'waypoint_name' => Input::get('waypointName'),
      'latitude' => $latitude,
      'longitude' => $longitude,
      'cts' => Input::get('courseToSteer'),
      'dtw' => Input::get('DistanceToWaypoint'),
      'hw_time' => Input::get('HWTime'),
      'hw_height' => Input::get('HWHeight'),
      'lw_time' => Input::get('LWTime'),
      'lw_height' => Input::get('LWHeight'),
      'chart_num' => Input::get('chartNumbers'),
      'almanac' => Input::get('almanacPages'),
      'radio_signals' => Input::get('radioPages'),
      'por' => Input::get('por'),
      'por_almanac' => Input::get('porAlmanac'),
      'por_vhf' => Input::get('porVHF'),
      'vhf' => Input::get('vhf'),
      'passage_note' => Input::get('notes')
    ));
    $recordID = $insertIntoWaypoints;
    $insertInto = DB::getInstance()->insert('ym_passageplan_route', array(
      'passageplan_id' => $getPassageId,
      'waypoint_id' => $recordID
    ));
    $return['success'] = True;
    $return['message'] = 'successful!';
    print json_encode($return);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    $return['success'] = False;
    $return['message'] = 'Could&apos;t update the database';
    print json_encode($return);
  }
} else {
  foreach (array_combine($validation->errors(), $validation->fields()) as $error => $field) {
    // Append an array of the error data to $return.
    array_push($messages, $error);
    array_push($fields, $field);
  }
  $return['fields'] = $fields;
  $return['message'] = $messages;
  echo json_encode($return);
}
}
```

And the AJAX segment on the form page itself

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(routePlan_form).submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/pages/voyages/passageplans/createroute.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $("#routePlan_form").serialize(),
    'success': function(data) {
      if(data['success']) {
        //refresh the table
        $("#table").load(location.href + " #table");
        //reset the form
        $('#routePlan_form').trigger("reset");
        //scroll to the top
        window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
        //send the user a success message
        resetToastPosition();
        $.toast({
          heading: 'Success',
          text: 'Waypoint added successfully',
          textColor: 'white',
          showHideTransition: 'slide',
          hideAfter : 7000,
          icon: 'success',
          loaderBg: '#f96868',
          position: 'top-center'
        })
      } else {
         var i;
         for (i = 0; i < data['message'].length; i++) {
         //scroll to the top
         window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
         this.error(this.xhr, data['message'][i]);
         $("#"+data['fields'][i]).addClass("form-control-danger");
         $('<label id="'+data['fields'][i]+'"-error" class="badge badge-danger" for="'+data['fields'][i]+'">'+data['message'][i]+'</label>').insertAfter("#"+data['fields'][i]);
         }
      }
    },
    'error': function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      //send the user a success message
      resetToastPosition();
      $.toast({
        heading: 'Error',
        text: '' + textStatus,
        textColor: 'white',
        showHideTransition: 'slide',
        hideAfter : 10000,
        icon: 'error',
        bgColor: '#f96868',
        position: 'top-center',
        loaderBg: '#405189'
      })
    }
  })
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently it looks like you're redefining `$return` every iteration rather than *appending* to it: `$return = array('success' => 'False');` as opposed to `$return["success"] = false;`. The following might be a step in the right direction:

```
<?php
    // Declare an empty $return array.
    $return = array();

    // Iterate through the errors and populate the $return array.
    foreach (array_combine($validation->errors(), $validation->fields()) as $error => $field) {

        // Append an array of the error data to $return.
        $return[] = [
            "success" => false,
            "message" => $error,
            "field"   => $field,
        ];
    }

    // Output JSON-encoded array to front-end.
    echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! That worked thanks and makes sense, however when there is more than one validation error it returns the last error and not all?

Comment: Perhaps I need a foreach loop in the AJAX?

Comment: Thanks so much for coming back - sadly I'm now getting an undefined message. Will update original post with new code

Comment: Do I not need to loop through the messages and display each message in turn on the client side?

Comment: Something like this...
var i;
            for (i = 0; i < data['message'].length; i++) {
              this.error(this.xhr, data['message']);
            }

Comment: @MatthewBarraud in your updated code you've missed out the array declaration: `$return = array();` - this might not make a difference as PHP isn't particularly strict but please try adding that back and see if it helps. As for displaying the errors, one way would be to loop through the array and append the error message next to each field/element. It might be worth looking into jQuery Validate as an easier solution, however.

Comment: thanks!!! I have updated the code as you mentioned - had got the $return=array(); but it was further up the page, sorry should have mentioned that. I'm getting closer, just need to split out the results now.